# Docker compose environment and paths

Tags: docker, fig, docker-compose

I am trying to create local development environment using Docker Compose. I started using this example https://github.com/b00giZm/docker-compose-nodejs-examples/tree/master/03-express-gulp-watch and it is working like a charm. No problem there.

However the structure in that example is too simple and doesn't fit to my needs. I am planning to run my application with coreos on production, so I need a bunch of other config files also. This is roughly how I CHANGED the example above:

```
application
   app
      bin
      public
      routes
      views
      app.js
      gulpfile.js
      package.json

vm
   coreos (production configs here)
   docker (development configs here)
      app
         Dockerfile
      docker-compose.yml
```

Dockerfile for actual application in there, because I would like to use separate dockerfiles for production and development use.

I also changed my docker-compose.yml to this:

```
web:
  build: app
  volumes:
    - "../../app:/src/app"
  ports:
    - "3030:3000"
    - "35729:35729"
```

After this "docker-compose build" goes ok, but "docker-compose up" doesn't. I get an error saying, that gulpfile cant be found. In my logic this is because of volume mounts, they don't work with parent directories as I assume.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Or I you have working example for this situation, please share it.

Comment: I think you might be hitting https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/858, you can try to fix it by doing `docker-compose rm --force` which will remove the old containers so you can't copy the old volumes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dnephin was right. Removing old containers did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your are probably hitting the issue of using volumes too early and trying to access them in cascading docker images.

See this:
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3639

Comment: Did you understand my point, that the example linked in my post above worked perfectly. After changing the structure and referring to parent directory, things broke. So your suggestion seems odd.